# How can I added the post's Categories to the site's top menu (like a page)?

Tags: menus, themes

Instead of adding pages to the top menu, is there a way to add a dropdown menu with all the categories, or adding individual categories to the top navigation menu?

I am using WP 3.9 with Shaken Grid Free theme.

Comment: Does theme use native navigation menus? Does it have dropdown menus implemented? What have you tried?

Comment: I am new to wp and I tried to poking around the admin side and did not see anything. I am not so sure how everything is structured yet.

Comment: Then you should start at docs probably, see [Menu User Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) :) Note that this site is heavier on development side, than just _using_ WordPress.

Comment: even a simple website starts with an <html> tag, and even that is called a developmental step. Everyone are on different scales of "understanding" how things work and therefore they are different developers. So a simple question to you, is not so trivial to me. Thanks

Comment: Your issue is perfectly valid by itself, however this might not be the best place to _address_ such kind of an issue. :)

Comment: Forgot you owned this forum, but everyone are entitled to an opinion I guess. Instead of wasting my time, and yours, a simple answer would have sufficed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're under Appearance > Menus, there should be a link in the top right-hand corner of the screen titled "Screen Options." Check "Categories" or anything else in order to add other items to the menus.

This is useful in other pages of the dashboard as well, because some important items (post revisions for example) are hidden there.

Comment: I also had to check the Theme locations > Primary Navigation checkbox in order to apply it to my theme. Thanks